# Can Someone Explain This Labview Code

Tags: image, compare, labview

I modified some Labview code I found online to use in my program. It works, I understand nearly all of it, but there's one section that confuses me. This is the program:

[image: Compare Pictures]

This program takes 2 images, subtracts them, and returns the picture plus a percentage difference. What I understand is it takes the pictures, subtracts them, converts the subtracted image into an array of colored pixels, then math happens, and the pixels are compared to the threshold. It adds a 1 for every pixel greater than the threshold, divides it by the image size, and out comes a percentage. The part I don't understand is the math part, the whole quotient and remainder section with a "random" 256. Because I don't understand how to get these numbers, I have a percentage, but I don't understand what they mean. Here's a picture of the front panel with 2 different tests.

[image: Test Pictures]

In the top one, I have a percentage of 15, and the bottom a percentage of 96. This tells me that the bottom one is "96 percent different". But is there anyway to make sure this is accurate?

The other question I have is threshold, as I don't know exactly what that does either. Like if I change the threshold on the bottom image to 30, my percentage is 8%, with the same picture.

I'm sure once I understand the quotient/remainder part, it'll all make sense, but I can't seem to get it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that someone tried to characterize difference between 2 images with a single number. The [remainder-quotient](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/quotient_and_remainder/) part is a "poor man" approach to split each  2D array element of the difference into 2 lower bytes (2 remainders) and the upper 2 byte word. Then lower 2 bytes of the difference are summed and the result is added to the upper 2 bytes (as a word). Maybe 3 different bytes each represented different channel of the camera (e.g. RGB color)?

Then, the value is compared against the threshold, and number of pixels above the threshold are calculated. This number is divided by the total number of pixels to calculate the %% difference. So result is a %% of pixels, which differ from the master image by the threshold.

E.g. if certain pixel of your image was 0x00112233 and corresponding master image pixel had a value of 0x00011122, then the number compared to the threshold is (0x11 - 0x01) + (0x22  - 0x11) + (0x33 - 0x22) = 0x10 + 0x11 + 0x11 = 0x32 = 50 decimal.

Whether this is the best possible comparison/difference criteria is the question well outside of this topic.

Comment: Same as above but shorter answer: It splits the color information into Red, Green, Blue components so they can be added together. It's an odd way to do the byte splitting. I would have "Color To RGB.vi" or the Split Number function (which is what "Color To RGB.vi" uses internally).

Comment: Thank you, both of you, I understand the whole program much more now. To explain further for anyone interested, it takes 2 images, subtracts them, and the image is turned into an array of every pixel. The array ranges from 0 (black) to 16777215 (white). The remainder-quotient section turns them into their RGB values and adds them (max of 765, 255+255+255), then the threshold (say, 30%, 229.5, I modified it a little) turns every value less than that number into a 0, and above that number into 1. It adds all the 1's and divides by the total picture size, and you get a percentage of light pixels.